# How to Configure SQL Server 2005 Replication through a firewall?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, replication, firewall

What ports or modes of communication do you need to open up for SQL Server 2005 Transactional Replication?  Main and slave are geographically separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you enable encryption, otherwise your replicated data could be sniffed by any one in between. The better solution would be to set up a VPN between your two locations to off load the encryption from SQL Server and also provide better security.

Comment: This ewas a concern I had as well, thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe TCP Port 1433 is typical although it can be defined by the publisher

[Here is a decent article on this.](http://www.replicationanswers.com/InternetArticle.asp)

Comment: Thank you this looks like the ticket, I'll have more time to look at it tomorrow and evaluate.

Answer (score -1):

(Not an Answer)

I regretted using SQL Replication back during the SQL Server 7 days.  From what I've seen of SQL Server 2005, The tools have become more unusable.

If I were in your position, I would look at some form of Transaction server that supports replication and set it up as a middle tier between your application and your database(s).